# Android incompatible types error

Tags: android

Upon compiling I'm getting this error:

```
error: incompatible types: <anonymous WebViewClient> cannot be converted to Context
```

The error is coming from this line:

```
progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true);
```

`this` is meant to be class `Context`, I think it's something to do with this, I don't understand what a Context is or how to fix it.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String urlNewString) {
                webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView webView, String url, Bitmap facIcon) {
                progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true); // the offending line
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                progress.dismiss();
            }
            public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/error.html");
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        });
        .
        .
    }
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true);
```

to

```
progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);
```

That line of code is inside the `onPageStarted` method of an anonymous class. So `this` refers to the anonymous class, not to the current activity context.

Comment: Thank you, that's fixed the error. But now it's running I can see there's something seriously wrong with the code, the google webpage doesn't load, and it doesn't respond to the android back button any more.